# How to calculate minutes difference next day for any datetime64 column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
Index   DateTimeColumn
5517    2015-04-20 15:27:30
5674    2015-04-20 15:37:30
5675    2015-04-20 15:37:30
5917    2015-04-20 15:49:30
5919    2015-04-20 15:49:30
6619    2015-04-20 16:18:12
6652    2015-04-20 16:36:30
6696    2015-04-20 16:21:42
```

I want to generate some time range say from 15:27:30 to 20 minutes. Or find next day.. Can someone suggest me code snippet for this task ?

Comment: that is range of minutes i.e 15:27:30 to 15:47:30 ( minutes )..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [pd.offsets](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) like `Day` or `Minute`:

```
print df['DateTimeColumn'] + pd.offsets.Minute(20)
0   2015-04-20 15:47:30
1   2015-04-20 15:57:30
2   2015-04-20 15:57:30
3   2015-04-20 16:09:30
4   2015-04-20 16:09:30
5   2015-04-20 16:38:12
6   2015-04-20 16:56:30
7   2015-04-20 16:41:42
Name: DateTimeColumn, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print df['DateTimeColumn'] + pd.offsets.Day()
0   2015-04-21 15:27:30
1   2015-04-21 15:37:30
2   2015-04-21 15:37:30
3   2015-04-21 15:49:30
4   2015-04-21 15:49:30
5   2015-04-21 16:18:12
6   2015-04-21 16:36:30
7   2015-04-21 16:21:42
Name: DateTimeColumn, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You can create new `columns`:

```
df['Minutes20'] = df['DateTimeColumn'] + pd.offsets.Minute(20)
df['NextDay'] = df['DateTimeColumn'] + pd.offsets.Day()
print df
   Index      DateTimeColumn           Minutes20             NextDay
0   5517 2015-04-20 15:27:30 2015-04-20 15:47:30 2015-04-21 15:27:30
1   5674 2015-04-20 15:37:30 2015-04-20 15:57:30 2015-04-21 15:37:30
2   5675 2015-04-20 15:37:30 2015-04-20 15:57:30 2015-04-21 15:37:30
3   5917 2015-04-20 15:49:30 2015-04-20 16:09:30 2015-04-21 15:49:30
4   5919 2015-04-20 15:49:30 2015-04-20 16:09:30 2015-04-21 15:49:30
5   6619 2015-04-20 16:18:12 2015-04-20 16:38:12 2015-04-21 16:18:12
6   6652 2015-04-20 16:36:30 2015-04-20 16:56:30 2015-04-21 16:36:30
7   6696 2015-04-20 16:21:42 2015-04-20 16:41:42 2015-04-21 16:21:42
```

You can find difference to next `Day` by [`normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html):

```
#df['Minutes20'] = df['DateTimeColumn'] + pd.offsets.Minute(20)
df['NextDay'] = df['DateTimeColumn'] + pd.offsets.Day()
df['NextDayNorm'] = df['NextDay'].dt.normalize() 
df['NextDayDiff'] = df['NextDay'].dt.normalize() - df['DateTimeColumn']
print df
   Index      DateTimeColumn             NextDay NextDayNorm  NextDayDiff
0   5517 2015-04-20 15:27:30 2015-04-21 15:27:30  2015-04-21     08:32:30
1   5674 2015-04-20 15:37:30 2015-04-21 15:37:30  2015-04-21     08:22:30
2   5675 2015-04-20 15:37:30 2015-04-21 15:37:30  2015-04-21     08:22:30
3   5917 2015-04-20 15:49:30 2015-04-21 15:49:30  2015-04-21     08:10:30
4   5919 2015-04-20 15:49:30 2015-04-21 15:49:30  2015-04-21     08:10:30
5   6619 2015-04-20 16:18:12 2015-04-21 16:18:12  2015-04-21     07:41:48
6   6652 2015-04-20 16:36:30 2015-04-21 16:36:30  2015-04-21     07:23:30
7   6696 2015-04-20 16:21:42 2015-04-21 16:21:42  2015-04-21     07:38:18
```

If you want select by time range, first set column `DateTimeColumn` to index and then [`indexer_between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html):

```
print df
   Index      DateTimeColumn
0   5517 2015-04-20 15:27:30
1   5674 2015-04-20 15:37:30
2   5675 2015-04-20 15:37:30
3   5917 2015-04-20 15:49:30
4   5675 2015-04-21 15:37:30
5   5917 2015-04-22 15:49:30
6   5919 2015-04-23 15:49:30
7   6619 2015-04-20 16:18:12
8   6652 2015-04-20 16:36:30
9   6696 2015-04-20 16:21:42

start = pd.to_datetime('15:27:30').time()
end = pd.to_datetime('15:47:30').time()
print start
15:27:30
print end
15:47:30

df.index = df['DateTimeColumn']
print df.ix[df.index.indexer_between_time(start, end)]
                     Index      DateTimeColumn
DateTimeColumn                                
2015-04-20 15:27:30   5517 2015-04-20 15:27:30
2015-04-20 15:37:30   5674 2015-04-20 15:37:30
2015-04-20 15:37:30   5675 2015-04-20 15:37:30
2015-04-21 15:37:30   5675 2015-04-21 15:37:30
```

You can create `start` and `end` time by `offset` by:

```
startdate = pd.to_datetime('15:27:30')
enddate = startdate + pd.offsets.Minute(20)

start = startdate.time()
end = enddate.time()
print start
15:27:30
print end
15:47:30
```

Comment: Thanks its working.. but could you please suggest me I can write a query on dataframe to selete all the date records from start to end.  Start = 15:27:30 and end = 15:47:30 (after 20 minutes)

Comment: Great !! that' really helpful .. but one change here is it possible to find the end = start time + 10 minutes. I can execute the query like > start_time & < end_time ..

Comment: Thank you so much.. I wanted to reset the time(hour,minutes = 0) after finding next day. as you suggested .   2015-04-21 15:27:30 df['NextDay'] = df['DateTimeColumn'] + pd.offsets.Day(). like example is 2015-04-22 00:00:00.. Please suggest your solution. This is last part of my requirements.

Comment: I think you can use `dt.normalize()` as I suggested in next row. Or you need something else?